# Progress bar not showing until after task is completed

Tags: winforms, multithreading

I have been trying to get a progressbar set to marquee to keep moving while another function is running.  After this function runs, I message would display (for this example)

The only way I was able to get this working was with a background worker and then have a

Do
Loop until condition that runs in the main form until the operation is complete followed by my message box.

This seems like a kludge way to accomplish this and a thread.start followed by a thread.join seems like a much nicer way to fix this.  However, I was not able to get that working either.

I have included a small demo program if anyone is interested.
http://www.filedropper.com/progressbar

Thanks

Comment: The code is missing. Makes this question much more difficult to follow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Thread.Start` and `Thread.Join` is *not* the way to do it - that basically blocks your UI thread again. `Application.DoEvents` isn't the way to go either - you really do want a separate thread.

You *could* then use `Control.Invoke`/`Control.BeginInvoke` to marshal back to the UI thread, but [`BackgroundWorker`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/interopmigration/bb380242.aspx) makes all this a lot easier. A search for "BackgroundWorker tutorial" yields lots of hits.

EDIT: To show the message when the worker has finished, use the [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event. The [`ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx) method and [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event are used to handle updating the progress bar. (The UI subscribes to ProgressChanged, and the task calls ReportProgress periodically.)

Comment: I am currently using background worker, but having to wait for the background worker process to complete by using a do application.doevents loop until seems wrong

Comment: Why would you have to wait for the process to complete? You want your UI thread to be free to respond to events (e.g. your window being redrawn).

Comment: Jon, the 'waiting for the task to complete' often *is* an issue - we're all agreed you can't block the message-pumping thread, but often there's a higher-level application requirement to not allow some other operation to start until this one's finished.  Modal progress dialogs rule, perhaps...

Comment: @Will: Yes, my comment was written in haste. I guess it should really have been: "I think you've missed the RunWorkerCompleted event" :)

Comment: I ended up using the RunWorkerCompleted.  I will have to do some major redesign for a couple of functions.  But I believe it looks a lot better than the do loop stuff and I will be able to sleep better at night.  Just wish I could create my own background thread and just do a thread.join.

Comment: If doing a Thread.Join was okay, you wouldn't have needed the new thread in the first place :)

Answer (score 3):

That is not a kludge. That is the correct way of doing it; what happens with the BackgroundWorker approach? The trick is to use the `ReportProgress` method to push the change back to the UI (don't update the `ProgressBar` from the worker).

Comment: the progresss bar is a marque, and I always thought a background worker was mostly for asyncrones processes.  But I need to halt the main program (except for the marque going) until the process finishes. Please see example

Answer (score 1):

Use Application.DoEvents() in your function from time to time so that your process has some time to process his events, including redrawing the form.

Alternatively, you can use a worker thread (like a BackgroundWorker) to process your treatement, while the UI thread is displaying your progress bar.

Comment: I have that in my do, loop already.  I was thinking I might need to use a delagate and invoke the method.  See my example

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer given by Marc Gravell, the BackbroundWorker has a boolean property WorkerReportsProgress, if it is set to false, when you call ReportProgress, the program will raise an InvalidOperationException