# C#: Wait until progressbar finished drawing

Tags: c#, progress-bar, wait, lag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Winforms Progress bar Does Not Update (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068720/winforms-progress-bar-does-not-update-c)

First time asking a question here for me.

I'll try to explain my problem using this code snippet:

```
progressBar1.Maximum = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    progressBar1.Value++;
}
MessageBox.Show("Finished");
progressBar1.Value = 0;
```

The problem with this code is that the MessageBox pops up at the time the for loop is finished, **not** when the progressbar has finished drawing. Is there any way to wait until the progressbar has finished drawing before continuing?

Thanks guys!

Comment: @janw adding my code to my answer

Answer (score 4):

You might want to have a look at `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()`. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx)

```
progressBar1.Maximum = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    progressBar1.Value++;
    Application.DoEvents();
}
MessageBox.Show("Finished");
progressBar1.Value = 0;
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way in doing it but I can't get it to work. Does not seem to help a bit, the bar still lags. I just copied and pasted the code, though. So maybe I am not quite getting this ^^. Reading the `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()` also didnt help for me :D

Comment: It lags? Or you don't see it progressing? With a maximum value of 50, it takes 8ms on my machine, so it is definitely not a progress that can lag.

Comment: Well, the MessageBox opens before the progessbar even starts drawing (I know it doesnt, but that's how it looks like).

Comment: Increase the maximum value for reference and check again, please. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Increased both progressBar1.Maximum and for loops up to 100000. Now I can see an improvement. The MessageBox now appears at approx. 60% completition of the progressbar.

Comment: But that's the case for both with or without the `Application.DoEvents();`. It's simply caused the the higher values...

Comment: DoEvents is evil, try not to use it.  You will cause yourself many issues with re-entrancy.

Comment: Correct! Though, I cannot see a point of re-entrancy in the given subject.

Comment: @fjdumont -- could you see a point of re-entrancy if the code given was in a button click handler?  Adding a DoEvents will allow the button to be clicked while the loop is running...

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are doing all of your work on the UI thread.  In order to re-draw the UI, you would normally need to pump windows messages.The simplest way to fix this would be to tell the progress bar to update.  Calling [Control.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx) will force any pending drawing to be completed synchronously.

```
progressBar1.Maximum = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{
     progressBar1.Value++; 
     progressBar1.Update();
} 
MessageBox.Show("Finished"); 
progressBar1.Value = 0;
```

The other methods that may work would be to use a background thread (with all of the extra Control.Invoke calls needed to synchronize back to the UI thread).  DoEvents (as mentioned previously) should also work -- DoEvents will allow your window to process messages again for a time which may allow your paint messages through.  However, it will pump all of the messages in the message queue so it may cause unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
progressBar1.Maximum = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
   this.SuspendLayout();
   progressBar1.Value++;
   this.ResumeLayout();
}
MessageBox.Show("Finished");

progressBar1.Value = 0;
```

Comment: Hmmm. Doesn't seem to work... Still the same problem.

Comment: With this you won't see the progress gradually updating.