# progress bar progress does not update until method finishes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have progress bar which i am updating from method which is at other class.
The problem i have is that it updates only when the method finishes too 100% and not at every iteration of the while loop like i expect.
At my code i am not using `BackgroundWorker`. ill be happy for a solution to my code without it
The class called Creator and within that class i have method called create which has pretty long while loop:

```
public void create(IProgress<int> progress){
            while(startTime < endTime){
              ...
                startTime += steps;
                progress.Report((startTime/endTime)*100);
            }
        }
```

In the main form i have that method:

```
 void UpdateProgressBar(int value)
    {
        //This code is invoked on the UI thread
        progressBar.Value = value;

    }
```

and then im calling the create method like this:

```
Creator creator = new creator();
var progress = new Progress<int>(UpdateProgressBar);
Task.Run(() => creator.create(progress);
```

Comment: Sorry, winform. ill update the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Winforms Progress bar Does Not Update (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068720/winforms-progress-bar-does-not-update-c)

Comment: a little off topic but you should really learn the c# conventions. it seems like you are writing java code..